# Is it better to use a for-each loop in a function, or a while loop and a “found” variable?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm taking an online intro-to-Java course. In the lesson on `ArrayList`s, there's an exercise in which we're given an `ArrayList` of `Picture` objects, and asked to call `draw()` on the first `Picture` that's in portrait orientation. We're given some code to start with:

```java
// BlueJ project: lesson7/gallery8
// Find and draw the first portrait in the gallery.
// Notice the pseudocode from the instructions has been started for you; your task is to complete it. 

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfPictures
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Picture> gallery = new ArrayList<Picture>();
        gallery.add(new Picture("degas1.jpg"));
        gallery.add(new Picture("gaugin1.jpg"));
        gallery.add(new Picture("monet1.jpg"));
        gallery.add(new Picture("monet2.jpg"));
        gallery.add(new Picture("renoir1.jpg"));

        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while ()
        {
        }

        if (found)
        {
            ....draw();
        }
    }
}
```

It seemed pretty clear to me what they expected us to do. Still, I thought it would be better to make a function and `return` from a for-each loop, rather than using a `found` and a counter variable. This is what I came up with:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // declare/initialize/populate gallery
        Picture firstPortrait = findFirstPortrait(gallery);
        if (firstPortrait != null)
            firstPortrait.draw();
    }

    private Picture findFirstPortrait(ArrayList<Picture> gallery)
    {
        for (Picture pic : gallery)
            if (pic.getHeight() > pic.getWidth())  // pic is in portrait
                return pic;
        return null;  // there aren't any images in portrait
    }
```

They seemed to really dislike it, though. When I submitted my code, I got this back:

```
ListOfPictures.java: Keep looking for matches while found is false

Score
0
```

Which is the better way of doing this? In general, should I avoid using “flag” variables like that?

**EDIT:** Yes, it is automatically graded. I've actually gotten an error on other exercises saying that the grader didn't know how to deal with my code and that I should post it on the forum (which looks suspiciously like Stack Overflow, only that no one seems to know [how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/about)).

I *will* be linking to this question on the forum. :)

Comment: Your grader was misguided.

Comment: Looks like your solution is valid, I'd go back and find out whether the tutor has a good reason to mark you down or is just stupid ;-)

Comment: Time to quit those classes.

Comment: You should report to the professor. If it was automatically graded then there is a bug in the grading system. If it was graded by a human being, they should fire the grader for giving 0 when in fact you should have gotten an A+. Online courses have forums where you can provide feedback. You could add the commentary you are getting on stackoverflow as a reference that there is indeed a problem with the grading. Keep up the good work!

Comment: `your task is to complete it.` Maybe that't why you got zero, none of the required code was filled out.  Shouldn't you have done that, instead trying something that doesn't exactly follow the instructions

Comment: you have not completed the given code. thats reason enough for online courses to give you 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an opinion, of course. Both ways, if implemented correctly, will produce identical output.

That said, your way is:

- cleaner
- clearer
- more reusable
- and avoids unnecessary variable use.

Whoever graded your question either doesn't know much Java or is being unnecessarily pedantic or harsh.

Comment: and it uses one additional method not needed, which contains two return statements, which raises a checkstyle warning.

Comment: @AlexWien Psssh, a) by default checkstyle only warns on >2 return statements, and b) if you look at the [checkstyle page for that check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/ReturnCountCheck.html), the rationale is: "Too many return points can be indication that code is attempting to do too much or may be difficult to understand", which is certainly not the case here. As for the additional method: like I said, it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @AlexWien You could make another `Picture` object, initialized to `null`, and then set it to the matching object and `break;` in the `if` statement. That would also eliminate the need for a separate function.

Comment: @Antonio yes, but break is not fine, too

Comment: @AlexWien Why not? Same issue about control flow? It seems to me that setting variables isn't a whole lot better—now you just have to keep track of what gets set where instead of what gets `return`ed where.

Comment: @ChristianTernus for debugging, one exit point is preferable

Comment: @Antonio break is a kind of goto statement, nice in switch-case orherwise less clean

Answer (score 1):

Claasic example of teacher wanting student to know difference between when to use `for` loop and when to use `while` loop.  Use `while` loop when you don't know how many ierations it will take to find what you're looking for.  Use 'for' loop when you know the exact number of iterations

Comment: So, instead of either way I posted, I should use a `while` in a function, and `return` a portrait image when I find one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the for-each-return pattern. In this case, the flag is an unnecessary state variable that would easily lead to code rot in a more complicated program.

Your way is better, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: the two return statements are not clean

Comment: I'll agree that returning null is bad, but aside from that i'd still prefer his version to the `while` version.

Answer (score 0):

My programming prof would have preferred the `ẁhile` solution. He said that every exit of a method or loop (loop condition, break, return, continue) makes it more difficult to trace an error or to prove a property of a method.

In my opinion, this is a personal decision. There are good reasons for both options.

Comment: your prof is totally corect, desireable is to have one return only.

Comment: Basically yes.  But practically, in some cases it is better comprehensible to use a `for` loop (especially in very small methods).

Answer (score 0):

For each is generally geared towards operating on EVERY item in the arraylist. With the found flag, you are basically stopping at the first instance when it is found.

Comment: Did you miss seeing `return;`?

Comment: Do you mean that the for each would NOT stop at the first instance that was found?

Comment: The `return` stops the loop once it finds a matching object, though, and without using an extra variable.

Comment: Yes, I missed the return! Nevermind :P